# Enhanced Ecommerce: Tracking Checkout Behavior in Funnels

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I am implementing Enhanced Ecommerce Tracking for the first time into a site with 5 different checkout funnels. Each funnel has a different set of pages and has a different length.

I was about to put it like this:

Product 1:

CheckoutEvent 1 --> AddtocartEvent --> CheckoutEvent 3 --> PurchaseEvent

Product 2:

CheckoutEvent 1 --> Checkoutevent 2 --> AddtocartEvent --> CheckoutEvent 4 --> PurchaseEvent

Now I get a sense that checkout events should be unique and just put once for the whole page: There is a fixed funnel concerning all products e.g. starting from

cart --> shipping details --> billing --> purchase.

Could somebody bring some light into this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on research, I am going to answer my own question if someone ever has the same thought:

- It is not possible to setup different funnels for multiple products with checkout, this feature is built to track a unified checkout process although yo
- Building those custom funnels is a feature of Analytics Premium